# sql дублирует значения

Tags: sql, postgresql

eсть такой запрос:

```
SELECT factories.*, factory_notifications.updated_at AS last_message FROM factories
LEFT JOIN factory_contacts on factories.id = factory_contacts.factory_id
LEFT JOIN factory_notifications on factory_contacts.id = factory_notifications.factory_contact_id AND factory_notifications.user_id = 4
WHERE factories.name LIKE '%УРАЛ%'
GROUP BY factories.id, factory_notifications.updated_at
ORDER BY factory_notifications.updated_at ASC NULLS LAST
```

Он выдает дубликаты. Есть немного измененный:

```
SELECT factories.* FROM factories
LEFT JOIN factory_contacts on factories.id = factory_contacts.factory_id
LEFT JOIN factory_notifications on factory_contacts.id = factory_notifications.factory_contact_id AND factory_notifications.user_id = 4
WHERE factories.name LIKE '%УРАЛ%'
GROUP BY factories.id
```

Он работает так, как нужно, но по нему нельзя отсортировать вверх\вниз.

Подскажите как модифицировать первый запрос, чтобы он выдавал данные без дубликатов (все нужно сгруппировать по уникальному ключу таблицы factories)

Comment: по каком полю дублируются значенияя?

Comment: @Yaroslav дублируются factories, из-за того что я ввел в froup by factory_notifications (которых несколько), но не вставлять туда я не могу, запрос не работает

Comment: СУБД какая у Вас?

Comment: @Yaroslav postgresql

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Как то так, если я все правильно понял:

```
SELECT 
    factories.*, 
    ftn.updated_at AS last_message 
FROM factories
LEFT JOIN factory_contacts 
    ON factories.id = factory_contacts.factory_id
LEFT JOIN factory_notifications AS ftn
    ON factory_contacts.id = ftn.factory_contact_id 
        AND ftn.user_id = 4
WHERE ftn.factory_contact_id IN (SELECT ft.id
    FROM (SELECT 
                fs.id AS id,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY fs.id ORDER BY fs.id) AS rw 
        FROM factory AS fs) ft
    WHERE ft.rw <= 1)
GROUP BY factories.id, ftn.updated_at
ORDER BY ftn.updated_at ASC NULLS LAST;
```

Comment: 1 результат)) порезано еще больше)

Comment: А не пойти ли вам в чат?